# Two-way Data Binding Between Scopes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I've created 3 directives, an XY area slider, an X slider, and a ColorPicker directive that uses the two other directives.

I've gotten everything working except being able to get them to move together when sharing the same model.

<kbd>[View Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uloTVGgfgxVAMfmQQ8OH?p=preview)</kbd>

In the above Plunker, you can find the full source and see what I mean about them not sharing the model properly. I'd like for it to be so that when one slider moves, they all move.

The values are updating properly in the 3rd (color-picker) directive, so I believe that's where the fault lies.

ColorPicker Directive:

```
angular.module('plunker').directive('isColorPicker', IsColorPicker);

IsColorPicker.$inject = [];

function IsColorPicker() {
  'use strict';

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      color: '='
    },
    template: [
      '<div class="is-color-picker">',
      '    <div style="background: {{ color.hueHex }}" class="hsv-container">',
      '        <is-xy-field values="xyValues"></is-xy-field>',
      '    </div>',
      '    <div class="hue-container">',
      '        <is-slider max="360" value="hueValue"></is-slider>',
      '    </div>',
      '</div>'
    ].join(''),
    replace: true,
    controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.hueValue = 0;
      $scope.xyValues = {
        x: 100,
        y: 100
      };

      updateColors();

      $scope.$watch('xyValues', function(value) {
        updateColors();
      }, true);

      $scope.$watch('hueValue', function(value) {
        updateColors();
      }, true);

      function updateColors() {
        var hsl = {
          h: parseInt($scope.hueValue),
          s: $scope.xyValues.x / 100,
          v: $scope.xyValues.y / 100
        };

        $scope.color = hsv2rgb(hsl.h, hsl.s, hsl.v);
        $scope.color.hsl = hsl;
        $scope.color.hueHex = hsv2rgb(hsl.h, 1, 1).hex;
      }

      function hsv2rgb(h, s, v) {
        var R, G, B, X, C;
        h = (h % 360) / 60;
        C = v * s;
        X = C * (1 - Math.abs(h % 2 - 1));
        R = G = B = v - C;

        h = ~~h;
        R += [C, X, 0, 0, X, C][h];
        G += [X, C, C, X, 0, 0][h];
        B += [0, 0, X, C, C, X][h];

        var r = R * 255,
          g = G * 255,
          b = B * 255;
        return {
          r: r,
          g: g,
          b: b,
          hex: "#" + (16777216 | b | (g << 8) | (r << 16)).toString(16).slice(1)
        };
      }
    }],
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem seems that for each individual colorpicker you create your own isolated hueValue scope. You need from your main controller provide a shared hueValue variable. I did some modifications to your code and will show it below.

### HTML

```
<div class="pickers">
    <is-color-picker color="colorObj" hue-value="colorObj.hsl.h"></is-color-picker>
    <is-color-picker color="colorObj" hue-value="colorObj.hsl.h" class="is-color-picker2"></is-color-picker>
    <is-color-picker color="colorObj" hue-value="colorObj.hsl.h" class="is-color-picker3"></is-color-picker>
</div>
```

I've added the **hue-value** attribute which will be synchronized across all color-pickers.

### isColorPicker.js

```
scope: {
  color: '=',
  hueValue: "=" //This line is new, this is the hue-value from the html
}
```

Here is a forked [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k7FVYBOCoVEiEtghxYc7?p=preview)

## Update

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k7FVYBOCoVEiEtghxYc7?p=preview)

Since the goal was to eliminate the extra hue-value in the HTML code it now looks like this:

### HTML

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div class="pickers">
    <is-color-picker color="colorObj"></is-color-picker>
    <is-color-picker color="colorObj" class="is-color-picker2"></is-color-picker>
    <is-color-picker color="colorObj" class="is-color-picker3"></is-color-picker>
  </div>

   Hue Value: {{ colorObj.hueValue }} <br>
   Hue Color:
   <div style="background: {{ colorObj.hueHex }}" class="hue-preview"></div><br>
   Selected Color: <div style="background: {{ colorObj.hex }}" class="hue-preview"></div>
</body>
```

All colorObj now contains an extra variable called hueValue which reflects what hue we have set in one of the three color-pickers.

### isColorPicker.js

```
template: [
  '<div class="is-color-picker">',
  '    <div style="background: {{ color.hueHex }}" class="hsv-container">',
  '        <is-xy-field values="xyValues"></is-xy-field>',
  '    </div>',
  '    <div class="hue-container">',
  '        <is-slider max="360" value="color.hueValue"></is-slider>',
  '    </div>',
  '</div>'
].join(''),
```

The important change here is that it now says **color.hueValue** and not **hueValue**

Further, the controller initialization is changed to:

```
$scope.xyValues = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100
};
$scope.color = hsv2rgb(0, 1, 1); //This creates the color object so we can assign the needed color.hueValue variable
$scope.color.hueValue = 0;
```

The $scope.$watch has changed to:

```
$scope.$watch('color.hueValue', function(value) {
    updateColors();
}, true);
```

Finally the function updateColors is changed to this

```
function updateColors() {
  var  hsl = {
      h:  parseInt($scope.color.hueValue),
      s:  $scope.xyValues.x / 100,
      v:  $scope.xyValues.y / 100
  };
  
  $scope.color = hsv2rgb(hsl.h, hsl.s, hsl.v);
  $scope.color.hsl = hsl;
  $scope.color.hueValue = hsl.h;
  $scope.color.hueHex = hsv2rgb(hsl.h, 1, 1).hex;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to do it without adding an extra attribute. Similar to how [ui-slider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-slider/demo/demo.html) does it, they only seem to have the one ng-model attribute.

Comment: Aha, well I've solved it now using [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/k7FVYBOCoVEiEtghxYc7?p=preview) However I did quite a few changed here and there. So look at the update in my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I took a look at your answer and learned a few things from it but it wasn't quite as elegant as I was hoping for. As a result, I've changed my approach a bit. I'm going to go ahead and accept this as an answer, but I'd appreciate it if you could look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/DYseEJIsqg4t96NCRuhi?p=preview) and help with resolving the issue I'm having with the digest in the XY pane and the background color being inconsistent across all 3.

Comment: Of course I'll help you in the right direction and may have a few other ideas that creates a more elegant solution. Now, I'm trying to remember your main issue and I'm not quite sure what you want your final product to look like. In the first example all `hueValues`were supposed to be synchronized across the three independent color-pickers, but the `xy-values`were not. In your latest modification it looks like you want them synchronized? What's the point of the three independent color-pickers if all shows the same color?

Comment: There is no real point to it, I'm just trying to to learn/understand how scopes and data binding work. I'd like them to sync, but it's not real important. The biggest issue I'm having right now is the digest error when using the XY plane as it causes a flicker which makes the background glitch to red.

Comment: Have a look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dcNd2yktZN3iujAhFIg6). I modified `isColorPicker.js`, `isSlider.js` and `isXYFields.js`, look for comments about new code. It's a new approach where each `color-picker` element `$broadcasts` its changes to all active listeners. Basically, if one element changes, all elements in the DOM are notified, if they listen to that event. This may not completely cover your question and approach, but I recently wrote a [post with a similar problem](http://andersrehn.se/angularjs-creating-a-double-click-directive-with-customizable-timeout/)

Comment: Nice, I like it. Looks like I'll have to rewrite some of the logic though because it's firing off the events multiple times and changes to the input box don't update the color picker. Nonetheless, this seems like it'd be a cleaner approach than `$watch`. Thanks. :)